# How can i Prompt user log in

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

im using the default web page that visual studio makes,but i want the page to first ask for user log in or register and then show the content of the page.[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqIM6.png)  ,how would i do that?

Comment: add the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller method... This is one of the first things a tutorial will tell you if you googled it.

Comment: isnt controller in mvc ?

Comment: Well, you haven't specified what technology you are using beyond asp.net, which MVC is part of. You need to be specific

Comment: im just using web forms without mvc

Answer (score 1):

On the default page, ask for login credentials. Then create another page that acts as a Homepage, and redirect to that page after login is successful.

Answer (score 0):

On every page in the page load event check if the user is loged in.
If not redirect to the login page

```
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");
        }
```